# how to get notification in a specific time with specific ringtone chosen within my app android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

In my application, user can choose a ringtone, and specific time. my application will send notification at that time with the set ringtone. 
Ringtones will be provided with my application.
I am confused what to use and where to start, Notification Manager, Ringtone Manager. 
I need a guide where can I start from and how the steps to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can start by looking at this: https://github.com/donnfelker/Task-Reminder/blob/master/src/src/com/dummies/android/taskreminder/ReminderListActivity.java
it is a task reminder that uses alarmmanager and notifications

Comment: It doesnt do what i want